# How to Minimize Browser Window using JavaScript or jQuery or Python

Tags: javascript, electron

Trying to develop a small app using python flask and electron JS, basically i am using electron for only to run Flask Python Script by using (child_process & Spawn) in electron main.js file also using (LoadURL(http://localhost:5000)) instead of using (loadURL(index.html)).

I did close the Browser Window using simple (Window.Close()) function in separate JavaScript file which is linked in the body section, but cant figure out how to MINIMIZE the Browser Window using only JavaScript or Python in the same file linked in body.

Cant use electron for this because i am not using index.html in loadURL.

Appreciate all the help i cant get on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [preload script](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) and [inter-process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)

It's as simple as this

```js
// in the preload script
// you can access Electron's renderer process modules here

const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

// you should handle the IPC call in the main process
// and call Electron's browserWindow.minimize() function
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('minimize', () => ipcRenderer.send('minimize'))
```

```js
// in the main process, you should have something like this

const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  ipcMain.on('minimize', () => {
    mainWindow.minimize()
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com')
}
```

In your JavaScript file, you can now call `window.minimize()`

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. want to ask you something else, how i can learn to find these kind of troubleshooting, is there any specific docs related to electron about this or is it the computer science degree ? Once Again, Thanks.

Comment: The best resource in my opinion is the [official Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/). It covers everything you need to know about Electron. Good luck!